# breaking nested loop java

Tags: java, nested-loops

Does the `return` statement in the following nested loop (in the inner loop) works like break statement? 
does it break out of the inner loop? 
thanks

```
for i   0 to n do
 current   A[i]
 for j   i + 1 to n do
  if A[j] == current then
   return (current, A[j]) 
return ;
```

Comment: Why don't you just test if it breaks or not !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` = Return from method **NOW** and ignore everything else
`break` = Terminate the loop and continue to execute rest of the method (depends on whether it is labeled on unlabeled).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: so it's not working like "break" no? cause if I've used break it would break out of the current loop but according to what u said, the return goes out of the method

Comment: @NavidKoochooloo: Yes. `break` will terminate the loop and `retrun` will terminate the method.

Comment: +1. I see too many examples of code doing `if (x) return y; else ...`

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact, that your code isn't `java`, the answer will be **yes**, it does.

Comment: this is pseudo-code, but the program is in JAVA

Answer (score 1):

It breaks out of the current method altogether (so effectively out of the loop as well).
If you just want to break out of the loop, use `break`.

(Also, note that you cannot use a `return` statement that does not return the expected Object type (if any).)